# Webdriver By.TAG_NAME fails

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Python 3.10.4 + selenium 4.7.2

File mini.html:

```
<html>
<title>test</title>
<head></head>
<body>
<form id="EmployeeLogin">
<input name="fname" type="text" value="First Name"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Code mini.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("//mini.html")
print(driver.current_url)   # file://mini.html/

title = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "title")
print("title.id: " + title.id)    # title.id: 1e110297-1153-4d1b-9e01-1644830284fe

form = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "form")
print("form.id: " + form.id)
```

By.TAG_NAME correctly finds `<title>` but

By.TAG_NAME fails to find `<form>` with error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element:
Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag ame","selector":"form"}
(Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.125)
```

why the error?

Comment: Works this for you? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find_elements_by_tag_name-driver-method-selenium-python/

Comment: In Selenium 4.7.2 ``driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("tag name")``  is deprecated, the syntax now is: ``driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "tag name")`` but in this case (<form>) is not working - albeit it works for <title>

Comment: It works on my computer with no error (same version of selenium, but older chrome driver Session info: chrome=106.0.5249.119). Try xpath `driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"""//*[@id="EmployeeLogin"]/input""")`

Comment: Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.125 here.
And no, """ ... """ does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Notice
driver.get("//mini.html") is a local file.
Moved to a server driver.get("https://example.com/mini.html")
and the issue was gone.

Guess Selenium is not a big fan of local files!